# How is the determinant related to the unit circle?

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, complex-numbers

Here is a STEP 3 question from 2018, of which the Latex code can be downloaded [here](https://stepdatabase.maths.org/database/db/18/18-S3.tex). I know perfectly how to answer this question, so **please do not answer it**.

> The  distinct points $A$, $Q$ and $C$ lie on a straight line in the
> Argand diagram, and  represent the distinct complex numbers $a$, $q$
> and $c$, respectively.  Show that $\dfrac {q-a}{c-a}$  is real and
> hence that  $(c-a)(q^*-a^*) = (c^*-a^*)(q-a)\,$.
>
> Given that $aa^* = cc^* = 1$, show further that  $$ q+ ac q^* = a+c
>  $$
> The distinct points $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ lie, in anticlockwise order,
> on the circle of unit radius  with centre at the origin   (so that,
> for example, $aa^* =1$). The lines $AC$ and $BD$ meet at $Q$. Show
> that  $$ (ac-bd)q^* = (a+c)-(b+d) \,, $$ where   $b$ and $d$  are
> complex numbers represented by the  points $B$ and $D$   respectively,
> and show further that $$ (ac-bd)  (q+q^*) =  (a-b)(1+cd) +(c-d)(1+ab)
>  \,. $$
>
> The lines $AB$ and $CD$ meet at $P$, which  represents the complex
> number $p$. Given that~$p$ is real, show that $p(1+ab)=a+b\,$. Given
> further that $ac-bd \ne 0\,$, show that  $$ p(q+q^*) =  2  \,. $$

This question involves a large amount of algebra, and one can easily get lost in it. However, there are some interesting patterns emerging in the problem:

1. Why $ac-bd$ appears? This is the $2\times 2$ determinant! What's really going on here? In complex analysis/methods books, I have not seen any determinants related to circles or straight lines. (For circles, we have cross ratios, which is something completely different.)
2. Are there any generalizations to $3\times 3$ or higher determinants?
3. The last result, which states that $p\Re (q)=1$, is also quite interesting. How to interpret this result?

To summarize, this question seems to be tackling a very deep theory in geometry in an elementary way. I try to find more about this in complex methods textbooks, but I have not found any.

**Can anyone explain intuitively what's going on about the determinants**, or **tell me where to read more about the geometry of the unit circle?**

**Just tell me where this question leads us to if we go any further.**

Comment: “For circles, we have cross ratios, which is something completely different.“ - Are you sure that they are “completely different“? ;)

Comment: @QiZhu Well, maybe not, but at the moment my mind is unclear about it.

Comment: To be a bit more explicit: a straight line in the complex plane is just a circle in the extended complex plane/Riemann sphere/complex projective line that passes through the point at infinity, so the cross-ratio continues to make perfect sense (in a manner made completely rigorous by the complex projective line picture). So, what you're dealing with from the very beginning is an honest cross-ratio of *four* points: $A$, $Q$, $C$, *and* $\infty$.

Comment: So I haven't got an answer for you handy, but I'm absolutely certain this is one of those situations where everything is computationally doable in the Argand plane but only makes genuine conceptual sense in terms of the extended complex plane/Riemann sphere/complex projective line.

Comment: The modern way to define cross ratios is with determinants (due to Prof. Richter-Gebert). So e.g. in $\mathbb{R}^2$ we have $(A,B;C,D) = \frac{|A, C| \cdot |B, D|}{|A, D| \cdot |B,C|}$.

Comment: I'm actually quite shocked to see that the English Wikipedia page doesn't even include a formula with the determinant (the German one does!) - it is often more convenient to work with determinants.

Comment: @QiZhu What is $A, B$ and why that is a determinant?

Comment: @ QiZhu Yes that is a determinant. But it is not the same as the determinant I mentioned above.

Comment: $wz^* = w\cdot z + i|w \times z|=|w||z|\cos\theta + i|w||z|\sin\theta$

Comment: @jkabrg What do you mean?

Comment: I probably should have clarified the notation, so $A, C$ are just some vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and so you have two column vectors which hence gives rise to a $2 \times 2$ determinant.

Comment: I only clarified the important relations of cross ratios and determinants. I didn't explicitly say it's exactly the one you find above. I'm quite sure one of the reasons your determinant shows up is because of the answer I wrote but I do not have time to check your problem more precisely.

Answer (score 1):

A  very partial answer: To me a determinant is related to some linear structure, and in the present situation I do not see any underlying linear structure giving rise to $ac-bd$ in a natural way.
In view of the lack of replies I imagine that I am not the only one having this problem.

The expression is intimately related to the fact that we look at points on the unit circle. For such points it is, however, natural that we obtain an expression for $q^*$ which becomes singular when $ac=bd$:

Consider the collection ${\cal D}$ of straight lines intersecting the unit circle $S^1$.
Say that lines in ${\cal D}$ are equivalent if parallel. Let $\ell$ intersect $S^1$
in the points $a$ and $c$ (which are the same when $\ell$ is tangent to $S^1$). Then the mapping
$$ \ell \in {\cal D} \mapsto ac \in S^1$$
induces a bijection between equivalence classes of parallel lines and $S^1$. For example, a translation of $\ell$ corresponds to a shift $a\mapsto a e^{i \phi}$ and $c\mapsto c e^{-i\phi}$, leaving the product invariant. In other words if $\ell'$ intersects $S^1$ in $b$ and $d$ then $\ell\sim \ell'$ iff $ac-bd=0$. When lines $\ell,\ell'\in {\cal D}$ are not identical  then they have a unique intersection point on the Riemann sphere $\widehat{\Bbb C}$, with $\infty$ being reached when the lines are parallel. The formula $q^*=\frac{a+c-b-d}{ac-bd}$ only fails  when the two lines are identical and we have $\frac00$ on the RHS.

There are other nice properties, like e.g. the involution given by the Möbius transformation $M_q(z)= \frac{q-z}{1-q^* z}$ which interchanges $a\leftrightarrow c$, $b\leftrightarrow d$ and the fact that $p(q+I(q))=2$ holds  in general with $I$ being the involution in the line through the origin and $p$ (for general $p$). But this is somewhat off the track as I don't have geometric explanation for this.